# What is the RPL DIS sending interval fixed in RIOT?

Tags: contiki

What is the RPL DIS sending interval fixed in [RIOT](https://riot-os.org/) ? In Contiki the DIS interval is 60 seconds and start delay is 5 sec.

Comment: You may get a better answer to this in RIOT support forums. Also, the `riot` tag here on Stack Overflow means something else.

Comment: I have raised an issue regarding this on RIOT github page. No answers yet. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.